# SQL CLR Integration - Define Function Parameter Type

Tags: sql-server, parameters, clr, mismatch

I'm working on converting a rather complex .NET WinForms program into a fully-integrated SQL Server set of sprocs and functions.

I'm working on a 3rd party database over which I have **no** control at all.

The unique identifiers used throughout this database are all `numeric(21)`. It doesn't matter if that's a good idea or not... I have to work within that constraint.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to code functions that use these values. So far, I'm using `System.Decimal` to do so, which appears to work fine when the code is called from within the .dll itself.

In SSMS, however, when I inspect any of the functions, the input parameter data type is `numeric(18,0)`. I'm assuming it is assuming that based on the `System.Decimal` type, but that's wrong. And the end result is that when I try to call the function manually (in SSMS), I get the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

The weird thing is that the calls **DON'T** fail when I call the functions from within the .dll. How can I override the `numeric(18,0)` designation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, I hate it when further googling finds the answer like 30 seconds after I post a question!!!

I swear, I've been looking at this for days...

Anyway, I needed to add a `SqlFacet` to my input parameter.

I went from this:

```
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure()> 
Public Shared Sub Check(ByVal ID As Decimal)
```

To this:

```
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure()> _
Public Shared Sub Check(<SqlFacet(Precision:=21, Scale:=0)> ByVal ID As Decimal)
```